# Change name of dll that is being loaded by another dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

This is all C++/native code, Windows, Visual Studio 2017.

I have some third party libraries that I build using their build system (CMake), but the way their build system is set up, it isn't very flexible in how the created dlls are named. One library builds 2 dlls, say A.dll and B.dll; A.dll depends on/loads B.dll and my application depends on A.dll.

My question is if there is a way to modify A.dll so that I can rename B.dll to C.dll, and A.dll would try to load C.dll instead of B.dll. (I know about using dumpbin and lib to re-create an import library after renaming a dll, but that's not what I mean, as that would require re-linking my hypothetical A.dll)

Comment: So you want to inject a DLL into a process?

Comment: No, I want to rename a dll after it has been build, and fix up the internal reference to that dll in *another* dll to match the new name I gave the dll. So all before running any program, nothing at run time.

Comment: I am not very firm with DLLs but if you have the source files what keeps you from changing the reference?

Comment: Why not simply modify the build process of A.dll?

Comment: Because it's all part of an external build process, which changes and over which I have no control. If I could simply change that I wouldn't be here asking this question. Look I appreciate your help, but the question is what it is, it's not 'how can I work around this'.